# How to loop a string without `times` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use `loop` to print `"¡Ruby!"` 30 times. It could be easily done with `30.times{print  "¡Ruby!"}`, or using `while` but as I am learning I would like to do it with `loop`. Here is my code:

```
word = "¡Ruby!"
loop do print word * 30
break if word.count < 30
end
```

After printing 30 times as I wanted,I get this errors:

```
"wrong number of arguments (at least 1)", "invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (SyntaxError)" and "syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting end-of-input word = "�Ruby!""
```

thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would like to avoid idiomatic ruby? There are easier solutions by far see @DMKE's answer for example. OR `loop {print 'Ruby' * 30;raise StopIteration}` if you must.

Comment: I just want to chanllenge you guys and my self by doing it in a different way, using : **loop** as @nextstep did , thank you for your time!

Comment: @engineersmnky: Oooh, that's evil. I like it! :-D

Comment: so, why am I getting negative points? I not a professional programer, so I'm not allowed to ask basic questions? and challenge my self with different ways of doing code?

Comment: I have upvoted your question - coz I too did not understand the reasons of downvotes apart from the arrogance of few "know-it-all" types

Comment: Because you weren't very clear to start with that you explicitly wanted to use `Kernel#loop` ("with a loop" sounds like a generic looping construct). Which is also confusing as it is very unidiomatic Ruby, which you didn't make clear you realize, so then I have to wonder if you need to be told that. Basically required way too much effort to figure out what you wanted and why.

Comment: I don't know if stack overflow should be used like a place for challenges. I think not. Aditionally, you weren't clear about what you wanted and why do you want to "challenge" people with a question that is not a real challenge?

Comment: It was for me, I'm learning at this moment, so I come over here, ask for help, (for the right help thanks @nextstep again) then I get this kind of comments from Abe Voelker and Julio Garcia wich it does not help at all, all I smell is arrogance as Wand Maker said. If you don't have anything good to say, better don't say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0

loop do
  print "¡Ruby!"
  i += 1
  break if i > 29
end
```

This will `print` out your string 30 times.

```
=> ¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!¡Ruby!
```

For a slightly more legible output change `print` to `puts`

Comment: No problem! If this helped then accept the answer (not just for my benefit, this helps to inform future visitors). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
enum = 10.times
loop { enum.next; puts "What, ho!" }
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
What, ho!
```

[Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises a `StopIteration` exception when the enumerator is at its last element. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2A) is your friend:

```
print "¡Ruby!" * 30
```

Comment: While this does not meet the constraints of the question. this is the best solution to the problem and is the most idiomatic.

Comment: OP specifically asked for usage of `loop` (Infinite loop in Ruby).